# ReactJS send POST/PUT request and get CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django, reactjs, cookies, django-csrf

I'm new to learn ReactJS and Django.

I set `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY:True`, and get `CSRF token missing or incorrect` message after sending POST/PUT from my front-end(developed by **ReactJS**).

The reason is I **can not get CSRF-token from cookie**.

By searching related topics, the solutions are all used `document.cookie('csrftoken')` to get token.

My question is ... **how to get token without cookie**?
This DFX problem stocks me for a long time.

Thanks :)

Comment: you can tell django to ignore the csrf for a view, but to help you with that please add your view

Answer (score 0):

@mohammed qudah

my views.py is as follows
thanks

---

class UserAddAdminUser(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

```
permission_classes = (IsAdmin,)
parser_classes = (JSONParser,)

def get(self, request, id):
    user_info = User.objects.filter(username=id)
    serializer = UserSerializer(user_info, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)

def put(self, request, id):
    try:
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=id)
        if user_obj.is_superuser:
            return Response({"an_admin_already": id}, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            user_obj.is_superuser = True
            user_obj.save()
            return Response({"create": "success to create a user"}, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"not_an_admin_yet": id}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```